# How can we keep the crisp part of French Fries for longer time?

Tags: french-fries

Since few time I observed that whenever I make french fries, after 15-20 mins of its making it is getting loose. Is there anything doing that we can maintain the crisp of the fries for longer span i.e. for at least 20 mins or so?

Answer (score 3):

I am no expert but I recently moved to a student apartment in the Netherlands and my roommates have some experience making fries.

I'd say one of the main factor that makes the fries get soggy is the steam that comes out of them. If all of the fries are very close together, like in a bowl, the fries will basically steam themselves. To prevent this try to spread them out as much as possible. What we usually do is put the in an oven tray (with parchment paper) and season them.

Answer (score 2):

The tip I hear the most with fries is, to double-fry them. First fry them till they are cooked, but still pale on the outside. Then let them cool off. Then fry them again, till they are crispy.

This should improve overall crispiness, but also potentially keep sem good for longer, as you´ll reduce water content.

That said, fries are greatest when they are hot. So try to make smaller portions and then make some more if you need them. With the above tip it´s easy, as you can have them prepared and the second fry does not take long.

Comment: Definitely this. Pre-fry on 140 °C for about 5-8 minutes depending on size, but since you said French Fries I'd say stick to 4-5 minutes, before they start to turn (golden) brown. Let them cool for 10-30 minutes, heat up the oil to 180 °C and finish in 3-4 minutes. For French Fries maybe less. This step will make them crispy, so just keep an eye on the color!

Comment: Double frying it won't make them oily ?

Comment: @The Dictator: No - not if you make them fresh from the potato at least. Never tried it with frozen stuff ...

Answer (score 1):

There are several steps to getting crispy fries that stay crispy.

1. Soak them in cold water, this will remove some of the starch that captures the moisture later.
2. Rinse them, after soaking just pouring off the starchy water isn't enough you actually need to rinse the surface starch away.
3. Dry them - pat them dry with a towel to remove excess moisture
4. Par frying (@320°F) first this cooks the insides to a soft & fluffy texture
5. Rest them at room temperature to cool off.
6. Finish fry (@375°F) The higher temperature will crisp them up...and they should stay crispy 'longer' than if you just slice 'em and fry them.

A Couple of short cuts:

- [Buy Pre-Cooked frozen fries](http://www.oreida.com/hot-potato-topics/2014/welcome-to-the-state-of-ore-ida). Several brands of fries in you freezer section are actually par cooked before freezing. All you need to do is finish them...and eat them. Fact is manufacturers (at least some of them) are doing step 1-5 for you.
- Get an "[Air Fryer](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_1_6?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=air%20fryer&sprefix=air%20fr%2Caps%2C162&crid=YS4VPAQNULPG)" These will allow you to 'fry' with significantly-less-to-no oil. Less oil = Crispier Longer